# Different approaches to interpolating a matrix

Tags: matrices, interpolation

Say we have a matrix

```
8 2 4
2 4 8
4 8 2
```

If we want to expand the matrix using interpolation to a 5x5 matrix, what are the possible approaches? Furthermore, what if we want to go even further and extend it for example to 21x21 (insert two times 9 columns and rows), etc.?

I tried the following two approaches and they yield different results:

**1st approach**

Linearly interpolate the columns:

```
8 5 2 3 4
2 3 4 6 8
4 6 8 5 2
```

Linearly interpolate the rows:

```
8   5   2   3   4
5   4   3  4.5  6
2   3   4   6   8
3  4.5  6  5.5  5
4   6   8   5   2
```

**2nd approach**

Diagonally interpolate the center points (each corner has a 0.25 factor/weight):

```
8   x   2   x   4
x   4   x  4.5  x
2   x   4   x   8
x  4.5  x  5.5  x
4   x   8   x   2
```

Using two new values and two of the initial values, calculate the intersecting points (each corner again has a 0.25 factor):

```
8    x    2    x   4
x    4  3.625 4.5  x
2  3.625  4   5.5  8
x   4.5  5.5  5.5  x
4    x    8    x   2
```

Looking at the resulting inner 3x3 matrices, they are different - the 2nd approach yields higher numbers. What is the mathematical background, how can I interpret the result and how can I decide which *type of interpolation* is better in a given scenario?

Comment: It would help if you could give us some context for this problem.  What are the entries of the matrix supposed to represent here?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom The matrix represents measurements made different locations and the goal is to extract a rough estimate of the values between the primary locations. The real matrix is a bit larger, about 20x20.

Comment: There are so many ways to do this. I don't know where to start. You can turn it into a super cool stochastic differential equation with boundary conditions if you want. It will leave your math urges satisfied but maybe not your customer? (What are your requirements?)

Comment: The general problem of filling in the blanks of a matrix is known as [matrix completion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_completion).  Low-rank completions are trendy in modern machine learning, but can be difficult to compute.

Comment: I see... The question is probably too broad. Matrix completion is the keyword I was looking for. Thanks nonetheless.